# Error connect android to asp.net core web api

Tags: android, android-volley, asp.net-core-webapi

I'm using asp.net core web api for my android.Inside my android i'm using volley to connect to my web api, my problem is that my android isn't connecting to my web api. Here are my codes.
asp.net core

```
namespace MywebApplicationIkeaExample.Controllers.api
{
    [Route("api/[controller]")]
    [ApiController]
    public class ProductsController : ControllerBase
    {
        private readonly IDetialRepository _detialRepository;
        private readonly ICareInstructionRepository _careInstructionRepository;
        private readonly IProductRepository _productRepository;
        private readonly IMapper _mapper;

        public ProductsController(IDetialRepository detialRepository,ICareInstructionRepository careInstructionRepository,IProductRepository productRepository,IMapper mapper)
        {
            _detialRepository = detialRepository;
            _careInstructionRepository = careInstructionRepository;
            _productRepository = productRepository;
            _mapper = mapper;
        }
        public async Task<IActionResult> GetCareInstruction(int id)
        {
            var careInstruction = await _productRepository.GetCareInstruction(id);
            return Ok(careInstruction);
        }
        [HttpGet("GetProduct/{id}")]
        public async Task<IActionResult> GetProduct(int id)
        {
            var product = await _productRepository.GetProduct(id);
            var productreturn = _mapper.Map<ProductDTO>(product);
            return Ok(productreturn);
        }
        [HttpGet("GetDetails")]
        public async Task<IActionResult> GetDetails()
        {
            var Mydetail = await _productRepository.GetDetials();
            //var t = Mydetail.OfType<Detial>();
            var Mydetailreturn = _mapper.Map<IEnumerable<DetialDTO>>(Mydetail);
            return Ok(Mydetailreturn);
        }
```

android
config

```
public class Config {
    static String ip="http://10.0.2.2:5000/api/";
  //   static String Regester=ip+"Register";
     static String Detial=ip+"Products/GetDetails";
}
```

WebApiHandler

```
public class WebApiHandler {
    Context context;
    String apiLink="";
    public  WebApiHandler(Context context)
    {
        this.context=context;
    }

    public void apiConnect(String Type)
    {
        switch (Type)
        {
            case "Detial":
                apiLink=Config.Detial;

                break;
        }
        StringRequest request=new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, apiLink, new Response.Listener<String>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(String response) {
                showJson(response);
                Toast.makeText(context,response, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        },new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

        }
    });
        RequestQueue requestQueue=Volley.newRequestQueue(context);
        requestQueue.add(request);
    }

    private void showJson(String response) {
    }


}
```

if you see i send request from my postman and get a respone but i could get this result in my android project
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mt4f8.png)

Comment: You are ignoring the error response. Take a look and see what that tells you

Comment: when i debug it, it doesn't goes inside it so if i put toast it doesn't matter

Answer (score 0):

Update: This is no longer a bug or a workaround, it is required if your app targets API Level 28 (Android 9.0) or above and uses the Google Maps SDK for Android 16.0.0 or below (or if your app uses the Apache HTTP Legacy library). It is now included in the official docs. The public issue has been closed as intended behavior.

This is a bug on the Google Play Services side, until it's fixed, you should be able to workaround by adding this to your AndroidManifest.xml inside the  tag:

```
<uses-library android:name="org.apache.http.legacy" android:required="false" />
```

anyone who is using asp.net core for web api in their android they have to use this code